Slow Workbook message -unused formatting and metadata can be optimised to improve performance
Using Review> Check Performance to improve performance is quite useful to me as I use a template workbook for most of my work which contains a lot of macros and data on various sheets.
After a while it can get quite slow - using Review> Check Performance clears this up nicely - is there a way to make this happen automatically within a macro?
Thanks
I used macro record to try and open Check performance and came out with
Application.CommandBars("Workbook Performance").Visible = False

which doesn't work.

The switches for Command Bars seem to have inconsistent performance as shown by the following subroutines.
Option Explicit

' Command bar is "Workbook Performance"
Sub sbWorkbookPerformance()
    ' Method 'Visible' of object 'CommandBar' failed
     Application.CommandBars("Workbook Performance").Visible = True
End Sub

Sub sbWorkbookPerformanceOff()
    ' works as advertised
     Application.CommandBars("Workbook Performance").Visible = False
End Sub

' https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/disabling-workbook-query-command-bar-during/88c48f46-00a4-4df4-b1e5-2ed28136b24e

    ' Command bar is "Queries and Connections"
Sub sbWorkbookQueriesOff()
    ' does nothing
    Application.CommandBars("Workbook Queries").Enabled = False
End Sub

Sub sbWorkbookQueriesOn()
    ' does nothing
    Application.CommandBars("Workbook Queries").Enabled = True
End Sub

Sub sbWorkbookQueriesVisibleTrue()
    ' Method 'Visible' of object 'CommandBar' failed
    Application.CommandBars("Workbook Queries").Visible = True
End Sub

Sub sbWorkbookQueriesVisibleFalse()
    ' does nothing command bar remains visible 
    Application.CommandBars("Workbook Queries").Visible = False
End Sub

Sub sbUsage()
 sbWorkbookQueriesVisibleTrue
 MsgBox "Done ..."
End Sub

